# Inconsistency in diff results for equivalent changes

Tags: shell, diff

Consider the following files and diff results:

**a1.txt**

```
a
b
My name is Ian
```

**a2.txt**

```
a
a
b
My name is John
```

Running `diff --side-by-side --suppress-common-lines a1.txt a2.txt` produces:

```
                             >  a
My name is Ian               |  My name is John
```

Which correctly states that `a` was added in `a2.txt` and `My name is Ian` changed to `My name is John`.

However, if I remove the `b` from both files, the produced results are different:

**b1.txt**

```
a
My name is Ian
```

**b2.txt**

```
a
a
My name is John
```

Running `diff --side-by-side --suppress-common-lines b1.txt b2.txt` produces:

```
My name is Ian                |  a
                              >  My name is John
```

This states that line `My name is Ian` changed to `a` and `My name is John` was added to `b2.txt`.

Even though the result of the second comparison is technically valid, the difference between `a1.txt` and `a2.txt` is equivalent to that of `b1.txt` and `b2.txt`, so why would the result not be equal?

Is there anything I can do such that the second comparison produces the same output as the first?

Comment: *[...] why would the result not be equal?* Your question stems from a misunderstanding of the diff algorithm.

Comment: @Jubobs Since you seem to know more than many of us about diff algorithm, pls give us a detailed answer in the answer section.. Will help a lot

Comment: @Jubobs can you elaborate? Or are you merely saying it is unreasonable to expect diff to interpret equivalent changes... equivalently?

Comment: @Ian2thedv There is a value judgement in "unreasonable", so I wouldn't go as far :) It's just that the algorithm computes the differences between the two pairs of files in a way other than what you expect.

Comment: @hazzelnuttie See my answer for an explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The discrepancy you observe between the two examples is normal; it just conflicts with your expectations of what `diff` does. The [`diff` utility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff_utility#Algorithm) solves the [longest-common-subsequence problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem), using lines as units/atoms.

> [...] the difference between `a1.txt` and `a2.txt` is equivalent to that of `b1.txt` and `b2.txt`, so why would the result not be equal?

Here, the longest common subsequences in your two examples are different and, roughly speaking, don't "line up" the same way. In the first example, you have

```
# a1.txt              # a2.txt                   # line in common?
                      a                          n
a                     a                          y 
b                     b                          y
My name is Ian        My name is John            n
```

whereas, in the second example, you have

```
# b1.txt              # b2.txt                   # line in common?
a                     a                          y
My name is Ian        a                          n
                      My name is John            n
```

Therefore, as far as `diff` is concerned, the differences between the two pairs of files are not equivalent. `diff` has no memory that all you did to obtain the `b[12].txt` files was to remove the `b` line from each of the `a[12].txt` files. All it sees is that the longest common subsequence now only consists in the one line that contains `a`, and it deduces the difference between the two `b[12].txt` files from that.

> Is there anything I can do such that the second comparison produces the same output as the first?

Short of using a different diff algorithm (or implementing your own), I don't think so.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation

Comment: Thanks :-) for replying